# Execute gcloud commands with python subprocess in Airflow task

Tags: python, airflow, gcloud

I want to build Airflow tasks that use multiple gcloud commands.
A simple example :

```
def worker(**kwargs) : 
    exe = subprocess.run(["gcloud", "compute", "instances", "list"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(exe.returncode)
    for line in exe.stdout.splitlines() : 
        print(line.decode())

    exe = subprocess.run(["gcloud", "compute", "ssh", "user@host", "--command=pwd"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    print(exe.returncode)
    for line in exe.stdout.splitlines() : 
        print(line.decode())

dag = DAG("TEST", default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=None)


worker_task = PythonOperator(task_id='sample-task', python_callable=worker, provide_context = True, dag=dag)

worker_task
```

I have this error :

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isatty'
```

Apart from airflow, these commands work fine.

I've already tried disabling gcloud interactive mode with "--quiet", but that doesn't help.

I don't want to use the GcloudOperator operator from airflow, because these commands must be integrated in a custom operator.

thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

As I see, your two commands are independent, so you can run them in two separate task from the operator `BashOperator`, and if you want to access the output of the commands, the output of each one will be available as a `xcom`, you can read it using `ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='<the task id>')`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use BashOperator?

```
worker_task  = BashOperator(task_id="sample-task",bash_command='gcloud compute instances list', dag=dag)
```

Comment: Thank you, But I would like to use the output of the commands